# Split a List of Lists with camel splitter

Tags: java, arraylist, split, apache-camel, splitter

I have many ArrayLists created to hold the collections of separate entities to be split in to their own entities. these are added to an ArrayList then pushed to the exchange where I try to split the List of Lists. I can't seem to split a list of lists.

Tried many variations of the Splitter, with tokens, etc.

```
List<String> serviceRecords = new ArrayList<String>();  //holds an assets collection
List<String> toRecords = new ArrayList<String>();       //holds all asset collections
```

after collecting the items belonging to a group, they are added to an ArrayList.

serviceRecords.add(sb.toString());

after all the items have been added, the list is then added to a List.

```
toRecords.addAll(serviceRecords);
```

I then push the List to the exchange

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(toRecords);
```

Then the XML route, it's in disarray trying different things.  none of which work.  there must be a trick to splitting an List of Lists.

```
    <route autoStartup="true" id="core.fleet.asset.splitterRoute">
        <from id="_from4" uri="{{fileEnrichmentEndpoint}}"/>
        <process id="_process4" ref="assetCollectorProcessor"/>
        <process id="_process5" ref="fleetAssetSplitter"/>
        <split id="FleetSplit">    <!-- strategyRef="tsAggregationStrategy" -->
        <!-- <simple>${body}</simple> -->
        <tokenize token="BLOCKMarker"/>
          <log id="splitBody" message="Split Body: ${body}"/>
          <to id="_splitOut" uri="{{fileSplitDestination}}/?fileName=GCMS_asset_${date:now:yyyyMMddhhmmss}.csv"/>
          <!-- <process id="getName" ref="fleetAssetFileName"/> -->
          <!-- <to id="_splitOut" uri="{{fileSplitDestination}}/?fileName=GCMS_asset_${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.csv"/> -->
        </split>
        <!-- <to id="_splitOut" uri="{{fileSplitDestination}}/?fileName=GCMS_asset_${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.csv"/> -->
        <stop/>
    </route>
```

multiple files generated from the splitting of the List of Lists.

Comment: What is the "exchange"  object? What is its type? What object do you want to split and based on what properties do you want to split it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know weather to delete this or leave for others interests.
After discovering that I was using the wrong List method, List.addAll() instead of List.add(object) and made this correction, my bad, Amazingly, everything works as expected theoretical expectations with everything in its realm, it works.

so it is quite simple. you don't need to do anything special to split a list of lists. 
the splitter will iterate over the List and split out the individual Lists.  you can then take hold of these lists and process them and forward them on.  Silly of me to think the mature Camel Splitter EIP was acting weird, it is doing exactly what it should be.

this is the end result. ( thanks to burki and others for your help )

```
    <route autoStartup="true" id="core.fleet.asset.splitterRoute">
        <from id="_from4" uri="{{fileEnrichmentEndpoint}}"/>
        <process id="_process4" ref="assetCollectorProcessor"/>
        <process id="_process5" ref="fleetAssetSplitter"/>
        <split id="fs1">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <log id="lfs1" message="Original Body: ${body}"/>
            <process id="pfs1" ref="fileSplitter" />
            <to id="seda:fs1" uri="seda:fs1"/>
        </split>
    </route>
```

I hide the file name inside the inner lists list on position -0- so we just extract the fileName, set CamelFileName, massage the data a little and send it to the exchange.

```
    log.info("File Splitter :: Start");

    List<String> pl = (List<String>) exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
    log.info("File Pay Load: " + pl);

    fName = pl.get(0);  //get file name
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelFileName", fName);
    pl.remove(0);
    log.debug("**** serviceRecords  ****");
    Iterator<String> pitr = pl.iterator(); 
    while ( pitr.hasNext()) {
          log.debug(pitr.next());
      }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    for (String record : pl) {
        out.writeBytes(record + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    out.flush();
    exchange.getIn().setBody(baos.toByteArray());
    out.close();

    log.info("File Splitter :: Finish");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JavaBean to implement the nested Splitter logic as you like.

If the standard [Splitter EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc) cannot do what you want, you can tell him with a bean how to split the payload of your message.

So, if you configure the Splitter to use your custom bean

```
from("direct:split")
    .log("Original body: ${body}")
    .split().method(new SplitterBean(), "splitServiceRecords")
    .log("Message part: ${body}")
    .to("mock:end");
```

And the bean simply collect all service records (from your example) in the resulting list

```
public List<String> splitServiceRecords(List<List<String>> body) {
    List<String> collectedServiceRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
    // iterate over List containing lists and add each item of
    // the inner list to the Splitter result
    for (List<String> serviceRecords : body) {
        for (String serviceRecord : serviceRecords) {
            collectedServiceRecords.add(serviceRecord);
        }
    }
    return collectedServiceRecords;
}
```

The List of Lists will become a single list with all items and each item becomes a message that is further routed by Camel.

Log-Output from route above:

```
INFO: Original body: [[Foo, Bar, Baz], [Record, item, thing]]
...
INFO: Message part: Foo
INFO: Message part: Bar
INFO: Message part: Baz
INFO: Message part: Record
INFO: Message part: item
INFO: Message part: thing
```

Comment: thank you, yeah i just bought the new Camel book.  It looks like I need to incorporate an aggregator - I can and have successfully implemented splitters based on a single ArrayList, CSV's, group and tokenize.  I just had a need for a List of Lists - an ArrayList containing many ArrayLists and ran in to a snag - seems in this arrangement special things need to be done.

Comment: I added an example that splits a List of Lists so that each item of the inner lists become a message.

Comment: thank you burki, excellent!  I guess after reading the section in the book, I am still confused. I'm going to try your solution above.  What I'm seeing is the spltter is splitting the entire arraylist.  from logs it appears the List of lists is being split as a single message.  I was expecting the splitter iterator to iterate over the List and split out the Lists inside it.  it doesn't appear to work this way.

Comment: Burki, I need to keep the inside containers (ArrayLists) in tack, as separate entities, then split these inner arraylists out.  each inner list holds a unique entity. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to split two times in RouterBuilder configuration

```
from("direct:split")
    .split(body())
    .split(body())
    .log("Message part: ${body}")
    .to("mock:end");
```